# Failed to install Ubuntu 22.04 on razer blade 14 (2021)

Tags: 22.04, acpi

I tried to install Ubuntu on my razer blade 14, and it didn’t work out. When I boost the installation from USB driver, this showed up a moment. Then it showed Ubuntu desktop and restarted.(PS: I disabled fast boot and secure boot.)

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You may want to take your question here: https://insider.razer.com/razer-support-45/ubuntu-on-2022-razer-blade-14-with-3070-ti-37086 It is possible but expect a bumpy ride.

Comment: Usually, recent versions of Ubuntu have better support for recent hardware. Try Ubuntu 23.04